# Retrieving size of datatype from std::type_info

Tags: c++, std, c++03

In C++03, when you use the operator [typeid](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid), a [type_info](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) object is returned.

Is it possible to retrieve the size of the given type based only on this result, such as returned by the [sizeof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) operator?

For example:

```
std::type_info info = typeid(int);
int intSize = sizeof(int);
int intSize2 = info.getSize(); // doesn't exist!
```

The issue is that we use a third-party multi array class that gives back a type_info, but not the size of the type.

Comment: Why not just use the type directly? What are you trying to accomplish that requires this?

Comment: We use a third-party multi array class that gives back a type_info, but not the size of the type.

Comment: There is no such facility as far as I can see...

Comment: I was afraid so, just asked because I've been searching online and couldn't find any resources confirming it.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can see (I would like to be proven wrong) is to register the types beforehand, like this:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

typedef std::map<const std::type_info*, std::size_t> sizes_container; // we cannot use std::type_index, but that's ok - typeid returns const std::type_info&, which refers to an object which lives during the entire lifetime of the program

sizes_container& sizes() // wrapped in a function to avoid static initialization order fiasco
{
    static sizes_container s;
    return s;
}

template<typename T>
void register_size() // Register the type. Can be called multiple times for the same type.
{
    sizes().insert(sizes_container::value_type(&typeid(T), sizeof(T)));
}

class no_such_type : public std::domain_error
{
public:
    no_such_type(const std::string& str) :
        std::domain_error(str)
    {

    }
};

std::size_t get_size(const std::type_info& typeinfo)
{
    sizes_container::iterator it = sizes().find(&typeinfo);
    if(it != sizes().end())
    {
        return it->second;
    }
    else
    {
        throw no_such_type(std::string("No type ") + typeinfo.name() + " registered");
    }
}

int main()
{
    register_size<int>();
    register_size<std::vector<int> >();

    std::cout << get_size(typeid(int)) << "\n" // get the size from std::type_info, possibly at runtime
              << get_size(typeid(std::vector<int>)) << "\n" << std::flush;
    std::cout << get_size(typeid(long)); // if the type isn't registered, the exception no_such_type is thrown
}
```

Possible output:

```
4
24

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'no_such_type'
  what():  No type l registered
```

If you can control how you create the arrays (for example, with a factory method) you can directly register the type here.

Comment: IIRC, there is no guarantee that all calls to `typeid` with the same type return the same instance of `type_info`. So `type_info` should not be compared by it's address. To workaround this `type_index` was added in C++11. If you cannot use C++11 write your own wrapper.