# How to get the size of data stored in "any" in c++17?

Tags: c++, c++17, sizeof

suppose i have a function like this

```
int writetofile(wstring name, any sdata){
  ...
   return error;
}
```

This function have no idea about what data would be stored but would need to know the size of the data stored in `sdata`. Although it is easy to determine the type of data stored in the `sdata` but i don't think there is some easy way to know about the size of data in `sdata`.

---

i have a data structure which has members of type `wstring`. Now We cant write that data structure directly to the file as it contains that wstring. As far as i have researched on internet, the best way to write `wstring` or `string`, is to write size first of the string and then the string. Then when i would read the string first reading the size then after this read that much of size.

for this i have made a function.

```
int filemanager::write(any data, fileid uid, DWORD *byteswritten) const
{
    // files is a map<fileid, fileinfo> where fileinfo is a struct which has 
    // members including file's name and handle 
    // fileid is a typedef of int
    if (!files.count(uid)) return -1;
    if (!data.has_value()) return -2;
    if (data.type() == typeid(wstring)) {
        DWORD sz1, sz2;
        wstring str = any_cast<wstring>(data);
        size_t sz3 = str.length()*sizeof(wchar_t);
        if (sz3 == 0) return -2;
        if (FALSE == WriteFile(files[uid].handle, &sz3, sizeof(size_t), &sz1, NULL)){
            return GetLastError();
        }
        if (FALSE == WriteFile(files[uid].handle, str.c_str(), sz3, &sz2, NULL) && sz2 != sz3) {
            return GetLastError();
        }
        if (byteswritten != nullptr) *byteswritten = sz1 + sz2;
    }
    else {
        // now if the type is not a wstring then just write it to a file
        // here i would need the size of the data stored in the data
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you count the bytes in sdata?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving size of datatype from std::type\_info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27522896/retrieving-size-of-datatype-from-stdtype-info)

Comment: How would you use this information?

Comment: @n.m. i want to write it a file

Comment: How do you do that? Please show some code.

Comment: Judging by the name `writetofile`, your plan is to write the contents of the type contained in the `any` object to a file. This will fail horribly for types that are not trivially copyable. Take `std::vector` for instance; if you copy its contents to a file, you'll likely copy 3 pointers. You need to copy the data the vector is holding in dynamically allocated memory instead. Please use a proper [serialization library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/doc/index.html). Anyway, I don't see how you're going to make serialization without knowing the type work

Comment: *then just write it to a file* HOW?!?! Suppose you know the size of the data. For the sake of the argument let's assume it's 42. What do you do next?

Comment: Proceed with caution. All of the crazy rigamarole, or some variant of it, you do for `wstring` you would have to do for any other complex type you may be passing in `any`. With `any` that is an insane number of different possibilities. You could restrict the possibilities with `std::variant`, but I think you are better off heading down a different path.

Answer (score 11):

`std::any` is not the correct tool for what you're trying to do. It is a tool primarily intended for communicating between points A and B, where *both points* know what the type is, but the communication needs to happen through some intermediate code C that doesn't need to know the type.

If B needs to try a bunch of different casts to see which value was provided, `any` is not the right tool for that job. The cast is there for type safety reasons: to have a well-defined failure path in the event that the wrong `any` was provided. That is, to make sure that A and B are communicating correctly. It's not there so that you can try a bunch of different things.

You can't ask `any` what the size of the stored object is because you should already know the answer. And even if you didn't know the answer, you could never *validly* use that answer.

Take your use case, for example. `any` is not TriviallyCopyable, so it is *not* legal C++ to copy its bytes directly to a file and then copy them back. And even if it were conceptually OK to do so, `any` may only be storing a pointer to the object it contains. So you'd just be writing a pointer to the file.

Serialization in C++ is not going to be as simple as you're trying to make it.

Comment: Took the words out of my mouth. boost::variant is probably the correct tool here.